# Unit Test to test the creation of a Domain Object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constructors

I have a Unit Test, which looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void Should_create_person()
{
     Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => new Person(Guid.NewGuid(), new DateTime(1972, 01, 01));
}
```

I am asserting that a Person object is created here i.e. that validation does not fail.  For example, if the Guid is null or the date of birth is earlier than 01/01/1900, then the validation will fail and an exception will be thrown (meaning the test fails).

The constructor looks like this:

```
public Person(Id id, DateTime dateOfBirth) :
        base(id)
    {
        if (dateOfBirth == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Date of Birth");
        elseif (dateOfBith < new DateTime(1900,01,01)
            throw new ArgumentException("Date of Birth");
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
```

Is this a good idea for a test?

***Note***: I am following a Classicist approach to Unit Testing the Domain Model if that holds any bearing.

Comment: Does the constructor have any logic that worth to be asserted after-during the initialization?

Comment: Never bother testing constructors!!! Construction should straight forward. Are you expecting fails in Guid.NewGuid(), or constructor of DateTime?

Comment: @Laiv, please see the update to the question.

Comment: @ivenxu, please see the update to the question.  Do you still think it is pointless?

Comment: It worth nothing to implement a test as the one you shared. However, I would test also the opposite. I would test the case where birthDate causes an error. That's the invariant of the class you want to be it under control and test.

Comment: Are you sure you're modeling an immutable object? Otherwise, you really can't make sure the invariant. Personally, I would put these kinds of invariant to private set method (property set) and have a coding conversion about never use field directly. Then the tests go the property method testing.

Comment: @ ivenxu, it is not an immutable object.  It is an entity object rather than a value object in DDD terminology.

Comment: Ok. that's right. Change invariants by *conditions of initialisation*. Or business rules. Whatever. The thing is that the constructor has a little logic around the birthDate. If you don't test it, you have no guarantee that your component is going to be always initialised in a valid state.

Comment: @Laiv, thanks.  Just so I am clear - you are saying create two tests i.e. one where a person object is created and the other where a Person object is not created because a date of birth exception?

Comment: @w0051977 exactly. In this case, the key test is what might cause the initialization to fail. I would implement test around this situation. The goal is to be sure that the instances of the class, (at least after the initialization) are going to be in a valid state. Keep in mind that as well if birthDate has setter and getters.

Comment: The test looks fine, save for one thing: the name. `Should_create_person`? What should create a person? Give it a meaningful name, like `Creating_person_with_valid_data_succeeds`.

Comment: @David Arno, thanks.  I agree that sounds clearer.  However, I will call it: Should_create_person_with_valid_state.  This is because I am trying to follow the 'Should' pattern.  Hopefully you think that is still clear enough?

Comment: @Laiv, what about the .equals method override.  Is it a good idea to test that as well?

Comment: @w0051977 if you find the `.equals`method to be relevant (because it plays an important role within the business of the application), then sure. I would. you have to weight "the relevance" of each block of code you put under test. For example, testing a getter and setter might not provide any value. Some `.equals`implementations either. However, it depends on the needs of each application. For instance, I usually never use equals, so if for any reason I have to use it, then I do test it. For sure, because something in my application is going to depend on its proper behaviour.

Comment: @Laiv, say I add objects to HashSets.  I guess this makes the test of .equals valid?

Comment: Great test. now load run this historical data though your program

Comment: @Ewan, I assume you are being sarcastic.  Could you explain? I assume you are an advocate of entities not always in a valid state?

Comment: This constructor has too much logic. If you must throw an exception if someone is born before a certain date, put it in a creation method/function

Answer (score 18):

This is a valid test (although rather overzealous) and I sometimes do it to test constructor logic, however as Laiv mentioned in the comments you should ask yourself why.

If your constructor looks like this:

```
public Person(Guid guid, DateTime dob)
{
  this.Guid = guid;
  this.Dob = dob;
}
```

Is there a lot of point in testing whether it throws? Whether the parameters are assigned correctly I can understand but your test is rather overkill.

However, if your test does something like this:

```
public Person(Guid guid, DateTime dob)
{
  if(guid == default(Guid)) throw new ArgumentException("Guid is invalid");
  if(dob == default(DateTime)) throw new ArgumentException("Dob is invalid");

  this.Guid = guid;
  this.Dob = dob;
}
```

Then your test becomes more relevant (as you're actually throwing exceptions somewhere in code).

One thing I would say, generally it's bad practice to have a lot of logic in your constructor. Basic validation (like the null/default checks I'm doing above) are ok. But if you're connecting to databases and loading someone's data then that's where code starts to really smell...

Because of this, if your constructor is worth testing (because there's lots of logic going) then maybe something else is wrong.

You're almost certainly going to have other tests covering this class in business logic layers, constructors and variable assignments are almost certainly going to get complete coverage from these tests. Therefore it maybe pointless to add specific tests specifically for the constructor. However, nothing is black and white and I'd have nothing against these tests if I was code reviewing them - but I'd question whether they add much value above and beyond tests elsewhere in your solution.

In your example:

```
public Person(Id id, DateTime dateOfBirth) :
        base(id)
    {
        if (dateOfBirth == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Date of Birth");
        elseif (dateOfBith < new DateTime(1900,01,01)
            throw new ArgumentException("Date of Birth");
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
```

You're not only doing validation, but you're also calling a base constructor. For me this provides more reason to have these tests as they have the constructor/validation logic now split over two classes which decreases visibility and increases the risk of unexpected change.

**TLDR**

There is some value to these tests, however validation/assignment logic is likely to be covered by other tests in your solution. If there's lots of logic in these constructors which does require significant testing then it suggests to me there's a nasty code smell lurking in there.

Comment: @Laith, Please see the update to my question

Comment: I notice that you're calling a base constructor in your example. IMHO this adds more value of your test, constructor logic is now split over two classes and is therefore slightly higher risk of change therefore giving more reason to test it.

Comment: *"However, if your test does something like this:"* < Don't you mean *"if your **constructor** does something like this"*?

Comment: "There is some value to these tests" - interestingly for me anyway, the value is showing that we could make this test redundant by using a new class to represent the person's dob (e.g. `PersonBirthdate`) which performs date of birth validation.
Similarly the `Guid` check could be implemented on the `Id` class. 
This means you really don't have to have that validation logic in the `Person` constructor any more since it's not possible to construct one with invalid data - except for `null` refs.

Of course, you have to write tests for the other two classes :)

Answer (score 12):

Already a good answer here, but I think one additional thing is worth mentioning.

When doing **TDD** "by the book", one needs to write a test first which calls the constructor, even before the constructor gets implemented. That test could actually look like the one you presented, even if there would be zero validation logic inside the constructor's implementation.

Note also that for TDD, one should write another test first like

```
  Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => new Person(Guid.NewGuid(), 
        new DateTime(1572, 01, 01));
```

*before* adding the check for `DateTime(1900,01,01)` to the constructor.

In TDD context, the shown test makes perfectly sense.

Comment: Nice angle I'd not considered!

Comment: This demonstrates to me why such a rigid form of TDD is a waste of time: the test should have value *after* the code is written, or you're just writing every line of code twice, once as an assertion, and once as code. I would argue that the constructor itself is not a piece of logic that needs testing; the business rule "people born before 1900 must not be representable" is testable, and the constructor is where that rule happens to be implemented, but when would the test of an empty constructor ever add value to the project?

Comment: Is it really tdd by the book? I would create instance and call its method right away in a code. Then I would write test for that method, and by doing that I would also have to create instance for that method, so both constructor and method will be covered in that test. Unless in constructor there is some logic, but that part is covered by Liath.

Comment: @RafałŁużyński: TDD "by the book" is about writing tests *first*. It actually means to always write a *failing* test first (not compiling counts as failure as well). So you first write a test calling the constructor *even when there is no constructor*. Then you try to compile (which fails), then you implement an empty constructor, compile, run the test, result=green. Then you write the first failing test and run it - result=red, then you add the functionality to make the test "green" again, and so on.

Comment: Of course. I didn't mean I write implementation first, then test. I just write "usage" of that code in a level above, then tests for that code, then I implement it. I am doing "Outside TDD" usually.